# chrono duration_cast not working when doing arithmetic in cout

Tags: c++, casting, iostream, c++-chrono

I do not understand the following behaviour

```
unsigned long begin_time = \
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();

//some code here

std::cout << "time diff with arithmetic in cout: " << \
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() - begin_time << std::endl;

unsigned long time_diff = \
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() - begin_time;

std::cout << "time_diff: " << time_diff << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
time diff with arithmetic in cout: <very large number (definitely not milliseconds)>
time_diff: <smaller number (definitely milliseconds)>
```

Why does the `duration_cast` not work when I do arithmetic within the cout? I have used `unsigned int` and `int` for the `time_diff` variable, but I always get good output when I first do the arithmetic within the variable initialization or assignment.

**NOTE**

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (Community edition)

Comment: I can repo it on MSVS 2015,  Cannot repo on g++ or clang.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, I thought it might be something to do with the compiler. Unfortunately, at the moment, I only have access to one compiler, the one I used to obtain the result above.

Comment: Actually [can reproduce](https://ideone.com/n662yH).

Comment: I am curious why you do not keep the duration and then do the conversion on the duration's after you get the end time.  I find [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d8313f798a7fe16) easier to read and use and I get the same values on all compilers.

Comment: As soon as you escape the type safety of the `<chrono>` system by using `.count()` you are far more vulnerable to run time errors.  Delay using `.count()` and `time_since_epoch()` as long as you can, if you have to use them at all.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was just doing some small comparisons (checking performance of code) between Python and C++ code, very informally. I was more curious as to why the code behaved as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably overflowing `unsigned long` (sizeof is 4):

```
unsigned long begin_time = \
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Recommended:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto begin_time = steady_clock::now();

//some code here

std::cout << "time diff with arithmetic in cout: " << 
    duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now() - begin_time).count() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `duration_cast`, the problem is that an `unsigned long` is not large enough to handle a time in milliseconds since epoch. From ideone I get this output:

```
Max value for `unsigned long`: 4294967295
Milliseconds since epoch:     15426527488
```

I get the number of milliseconds by directly outpouting:

```
std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() << std::endl;
```

In your first output, you get a gigantic number because `begin_time` is cast to `std::chrono::milliseconds::rep` (the return type of `.count()`) which is large enough to handle the `time_since_epoch` (guaranted by the standard), while in your second output, both value are truncated by the `unsigned long` and thus you get a (probably) correct result.

*Note: There may be architecture where an `unsigned long` is enough to handle this but you should not rely on it and directly use the arithmetic operators provided for `std::chrono::duration`.*